# How to remove a circular reference from relational database

Tags: database, database-design, schema, relational-database

Let's say I'm building a chat which has groups and rooms. I need to create relational database scheme for it.

- Each group can have multiple rooms.
- And each group always has exactly 1 main room (which is also the same room as other)
- Room has already prebuilt (despite it's main room or not) structure and can't be duplicated. Like foreign keys to it, or description, notification settings etc.

So since it's one to many relationship the following db schema could represent this model:

```
,-----------------.
|Group            |
|-----------------|
|*id: pk          |
|*name: string    |
|*main_room_id: fk|
`-----------------'
      ↑      ᗐ             
      ᗑ      ↓       
  ,-------------.  
  |Room         |  
  |-------------|  
  |*id:         |  
  |*name: string|
  |*notif: bool |    
  |*group_id: fk|  
  `-------------'
```

But I'd like to avoid circular reference in this scheme. I can do this by having boolean field in a room that says that this is a main room:

```
 ,-------------.  
 |Group        |  
 |-------------|  
 |*id: pk      |  
 |*name: string|  
 `-------------'  
         ↑        
         ᗑ        
,----------------.
|Room            |
|----------------|
|*id:            |
|*name: string   |
|*notif: bool    |
|*group_id: fk   |
|*is_main: bool  |
`----------------'
```

But in using this scheme database is not normalized. Main room `is_main` boolean field depends on others room `is_main` field. Furthermore more complex constrain should be created to support data consistency.

What is the appropriate database schema for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Group GRP exists.
--
group {GRP}
   PK {GRP}
```

```
-- Room ROM exists.
--
room {ROM}
  PK {ROM}
```

- Each room belongs to *at most one* group;
  each group *may* own *more than one* room.

```
-- Room ROM is owned by group GRP.
--
room_group {ROM, GRP}
        PK {ROM}
        SK {ROM, GRP}

FK1 {ROM} REFERENCES room  {ROM}
FK2 {GRP} REFERENCES group {GRP}
```

- Each group has *at most one* main room;
  each main room belongs to *exactly one* group.
- If a room is a main room for a group,
  then that room must belong to that group.

```
-- Room ROM is main room for group GRP.
--
main_room {GRP, ROM}
       PK {GRP}
       AK {ROM}

        FK {ROM, GRP} REFERENCES
room_group {ROM, GRP}
```

---

Notes:

Note that having a main room is not mandatory in the model, use application level to enforce it.

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a many-to-one relationship. Suppose I understood correctly,  each group can be associated with multiple rooms in our schema, and each room can also be associated with one or more groups, so it means it's a many-to-many relationship.

For example, let's say you  can have these associations in your schema:

```
Group     Room
group_1   room_1
group_1   room_2
group_2   room_1
group_2   room_2
```

It would be best if you create a new entity to hold the relationship between the room and the group entities. On this new entity, you can have a boolean field to indicate which association is the `main` one.

Comment: Nope, a room can belong to a single group. Groups can't share rooms in other words. Also room can be groupless. Despite it's M2O or M2M your structure is still denormalized (when you have boolean on m2m table)